# Any way to find IBM websphere nodeagents are down

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-8, jython-2.5, jacl

Is there any tool or script which continuously check whether IBM Websphere nodeagents are down or not. if down it could send a notification via email (concerned person). if there is any your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect someone gave you -1 for not giving info about your environment or what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a process-monitoring tool or custom scripts that look for the "nodeagent" process in the system process list.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup restart of your node agents via /etc/inittab

http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=matt&product=was-nd-mp&topic=trunprocessrestart

Answer (score 0):

I would normally do this by consistently checking nodeagent PID on the system and notify the people but if you require a auto re-start on nodeagent then you can configure it in /etc/inittab as explained in the link provided in previous response.
Thanks
Note: These opinions are my own.

Answer (score 0):

This will do ya.  Modify srvinfoList and sendmail then paste into powershell.

```
function sendMail($smtpServer, $Eto, $EFrom, $ESubject, $EBody) { 
 $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage ; $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer) ; $msg.From = $EFrom ; $msg.ReplyTo = $EFrom ; $msg.To.Add($Eto) ; $msg.subject = $ESubject ; $msg.IsBodyHTML = $false ; $msg.body = $Ebody ; $smtp.Send($msg)}

Function CheckServers($srvlist) {
 ForEach ($srv in $srvlist) { 
  $SrvName = $srv.split(",")[0] ; $path = "\\" + $SrvName + $srv.split(",")[1]
  $PIDs = (Get-ChildItem -recurse $path | %{if($_ -match ".pid") {$_.name} })
  $ProcInfo = foreach($PIDName in $PIDS) { $PIDName + "`t" + (get-content ($path + $PIDName.substring(0, $PIDName.Length -4) + "\" + $PIDName)) }
  $perflist = (get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process -computername $SrvName) 
  foreach ($perf in $perflist) { $SrvName + "`t" + $perf.PercentProcessorTime + "`t" + $perf.IdProcess + "`t" + [system.math]::ceiling($perf.WorkingSetPrivate/1024000) + "`t" + (LU_PIDNAME $perf.IdProcess $ProcInfo $perf.name) }}}

Function LU_PIDNAME($PIDsrch,$PIDdata,$PIDefault) { foreach ($PID1 in $PIDdata) { if ($PID1.split("`t")[1] -eq $PIDsrch) { $PID1.split("`t")[0] ; $PIDefault = $False } } if($PIDefault -ne $False) { $PIDefault } }

$srvinfoList=@((@"
WAS7ND1,\d$\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\
WAS7ND2,\d$\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\
"@).split(10))

while($true){
 cls;"Checking Servers for nodeagent`n"
 $Results = CheckServers $srvinfoList ; $Results
 if((($Results -match "nodeagent").count -eq 0)) {sendMail "mail.isp.com" "oncall@myoffice.com" "NodeCheck@myoffice.com" "NodeCheck" "Node is Down"}
 start-sleep -seconds 60 }
```